How to read all NTFS files with PowerShell?
AFAIK, NTFSDirect allows us to access the MFT directly to obtain information about the files and directories on an NTFS volume.
C# code:
string vol = "c:";

var fileList = new NTFSDirect.Enumerator(vol, new [] {".txt", ".md"});

foreach(string file in fileList) 
{
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(file);
    if (!f.Exists) { continue; } //every file is enumerated even ones we don't have access to.

are C# code which can do it. But I've not seen it wrapped in PowerShell.
How can I do this via PowerShell script?

Are you asking how to invoke your C# method in PowerShell, or how to use NTFSDirect directly from PowerShell?

AFAIK , The fastest way is going to be to scan the volume's Master File Table, the way WizTree does.  I want to use NTFSDirect directly from PowerShell. is it possible ? Also , there is https://sourceforge.net/projects/ntfsreader/   open source library that is written in C# by Danny Couture.
